# How to make differently route name in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two the same controller in different directories.

And routing is for both:

```
Route::resource('dashboard/statistic', 'Admin\StatisticController');
Route::resource('statistic', 'StatisticController');

When I run php artisan route:list
```

I see, that these routes have the same route name as: `statistic`:

```
statistic.index
statistic.destroy
statistic.edit
```

How can I make this diffrently?

Comment: It's all in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes

Comment: Okay, then how do this for `resource`

Comment: Also in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes - http://i.imgur.com/MZEMKLf.png

Answer (score 0):

You could to create each route explicitly (`Route::resource creates multiple routes to handle a variety of RESTful actions on the resource`), for example

```
  Route::get('dashboard/statistic', ['as' => 'dashboard-statistic.index', 'uses' => 'Admin\StatisticController@index']);
  Route::delete('dashboard/statistic', ['as' => 'dashboard-statistic.destroy', 'uses' => 'Admin\StatisticController@destroy']);
  Route::put('dashboard/statistic', ['as' => 'dashboard-statistic.edit', 'uses' => 'Admin\StatisticController@edit']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe

```
  Route::resource('dashboard/statistic', 'Admin\StatisticController',
                ['admin' => ['create', 'store', 'update', 'destroy']]);
    Route::resource('statistic', 'StatisticController');
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem